# I can't open page in Spring BOOT+MVC

Tags: maven, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I want create Spring boot project with Spring MVC.
I created Controller:

```
@Controller
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public ModelAndView index() {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("start");
        modelAndView.addObject("message", "hello");
        return modelAndView;
    }
}
```

Application Class

```
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);

        System.out.println("Let's inspect the beans provided by Spring Boot:");

        String[] beanNames = ctx.getBeanDefinitionNames();
        Arrays.sort(beanNames);
        for (String beanName : beanNames) {
            System.out.println(beanName);
        }
    }
}
```

and html page start.html

<

```
!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Getting Started: Handling Form Submission</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
<h1>Result</h1>
<p th:text="'id: ' " />
<p th:text="'content: '" />
<a href="/greeting">Submit another message</a>
</body>
</html>
```

So I have maven pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>Boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>Boot</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
            <version>1.19</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.axet</groupId>
            <artifactId>kaptcha</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.thymeleaf/thymeleaf-spring4 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring4</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

My project is build but when i tried open page I have error

> http://localhost:8080/
>
> Whitelabel Error Page
>
> This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing
>   this as a fallback.
>
> Wed Jun 15 14:20:53 ALMT 2016 There was an unexpected error (type=Not
>   Found, status=404). No message available

I tried add `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` but not helped.

**EDIT**

Now I can return JSON

```
@RequestMapping("/")
    public @ResponseBody Greeting index() {
        return new Greeting(1L, "sefsfdf");
    }
```

but How can i return `ModelView`?

Comment: Where did you put the html template in your project?

Comment: weppapp->pages  ...........

Comment: @user5620472 Please follow boot best practices. Templates to belong into /src/main/resources/templates. And most of your maven dependencies are actually not necessary and just blowing up your app. If you want to use thymeleaf use `spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf` instead of the normal `thymeleaf-spring4` one. Also all your dependencies for servlet, jstl and jsp are not necessary – especially not if you are using thymeleaf.

Comment: @daniel.eichten Can do you share some example how create spring boot+spring mvc?

Comment: Go to http://start.spring.io, configure the modules you need (Web, Thymeleaf, actuator, …) and start to move your code in. Besides that go to http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/ and read about the modules you are using and where to put what.